# Does linux have pause/resume feature like in Windows 8?

Tags: file-manager, file-browser

I'm looking for some feature which will allow me to pause/resume copy-paste process similar to windows 8. Is there any file manager that will allow this process? Is it extension to file-manager. Does this process have anything to do with file-manager? I'm also searching for portable and best file-manager too. I'm little bit confused choosing between PCMan and Krusader. Any suggestion which to choose between them.

Comment: You can always suspend the process that does the copying by sending it a  SIGSTOP signal (and a SIGCONT to resume).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Terminal Method

Usually when copying files that I think I'll need to pause/resume I'll go to the terminal and use the `rsync` command instead.

```
$ rsync -avz <source> <destination>
```

This can be paused/resumed in the sense that you can simply stop it, and restart the command later on. Only the files that haven't been copied as of yet, will get copied during the 2nd run.

The `rsync` tool is extremely powerful, and you can do a whole lot more with it, this is just the tip of the iceberg.

#### GUI Method

If you want to do this through a GUI there are a number of options listed on the  [alternativesto.net](http://alternativeto.net/) website. Specifically if you look under the alternatives to [SuperCopier](http://alternativeto.net/software/supercopier/), a similar tool for Windows. This list provides tools that can do this for all OSes.

If I were to pick one, I'd start with this one, [UltraCopier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/).

[image: ss of ultracopier]

#### Backgrounding the GUI

Another method to accomplish a pause/resume feature would be to invoke the file browser from a terminal and simply press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to pause the process. When you're ready to restart it, in the terminal from where it was launched, type `fg` to bring that process back to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

pcmanfm have that as a builtin feature!

Comment: This may be true, but it would be a better answer if it also described how to.